# How to do double loop and create table?

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R and I come from a Stata and SAS background. I normally used loops to create variables and to speed up processes.

I am doing the following: 1) I need to run a loop "I" 4 times for values 10,20,100 and 1000, and store 4 values in a vector or in a table. Loop I runs a process 100 times. Therefore, we would have 400 repetitions combined.

First. My loop needs to make 100 samples of size 10, see how many of those samples fulfill a condition and store the number.
Then make 100 samples of size 20, and see how many of those samples meet the condition...etc.

```
This is the variable for the sample size

    v=c(10,20,100,1000)  
This variable will store the number of observations that meet the condition
    sum.x=c(0,0,0,0)  
This is the variable for the 100 repetitions.

    sample = matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=100)  
This is the loop.

    for (x in seq(along=v)){
    for (i in 1:100) {
      data=rnorm(`v`,0.25,1)
      test=t.test(data)
      sample[i,1]=test$p.value
    }
    sum.x[v]=sum(sample>0.05)  
      }
```

The code runs fine, except that it just does not do what I need to:

1) sum.x has 1000 observations instead of 4. I know that !"[v]" is indicating the position of the row or something. I just want to create a vector/variable named as below and create a small table:

```
table=data.fram(sum.x10, sum.x20, sum.x100, sum.x1000).
```

2) The data has only 4 observations instead of 100.The main problem is that I do not know how to make the connection between the four sample sizes with the 100.

Thanks.

Comment: your first loop has index `x`, but inside the loop you use `v`

Comment: "sum.x[v]" is the same as "c(sum.x[10],sum.x[20],sum.x[100],sum.x[1000])". Hence after the last statement in your script "sum.x" has length 1000.

Comment: I know there's a mistake with the loop and I do understand the reason. The problem is that I just do not know how to connect those two things I want to do. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most R people depreciate loops. Perhaps this works:

```
v=c(10,20,100,1000)  

f <- function(n)
{
  sum( sapply( rep(n,100),
       function(n){t.test(rnorm(n,0.25,1))[["p.value"]] > 0.05} ) )
}

table <- sapply(v,f)
```

.

```
> table
[1] 83 81 40  0
```

- The function

  ```
  function(n){t.test(rnorm(n,0.25,1))[["p.value"]] > 0.05}
  ```

  inside the function `f` takes ***one*** random sample of size `n` from
  a normal distribution with mean 0.25 and standard deviation 1,
  performs a t-test using this random sample as data values, and
  checks if its p-value is larger than 0,05.
  The resulting logical value is TRUE if and only if the random sample
  meets the condition that the p-value is larger than 0.05.
- Then

  ```
  sapply(rep(n,100),function(n){...})
  ```

  applies this function to each component of the vector rep(n,100).
  This means that the test is repeated 100 times.
  The result is a logical vector of length 100.
- Now

  ```
  sum(sapply(...))
  ```

  sums the entries of this logical vector,
  where TRUE and FALSE are taken as 1 and 0, respectively.
  Hence the result is the number of t-tests
  which meet the condition that the p-value is larger than 0.05.

Finally

```
sapply(c(10,20,100,1000),f)
```

creates the vector

```
c(f(10,f(20),f(100),f(1000)).
```

To get more information than just this final table, one can split up the calculation as follows:

```
v=c(10,20,100,1000)  

g <- function(n,m)
{
  sapply( rep(n,m),
          function(n){t.test(rnorm(n,0.25,1))} )
}

f <- function(n)
{
  sum(g(n,100)["p.value",]>0.05)
}

table <- sapply(v,f)
```

Now `g(n,m)` is a matrix with 9 rows and `m` columns. The i-th column contains the result of the i-th t-test, e.g.

```
> g(10,5)
            [,1]                [,2]                [,3]                [,4]                [,5]               
statistic   1.117835            0.3290155           1.610792            1.399736            0.8213012          
parameter   9                   9                   9                   9                   9                  
p.value     0.2925871           0.749671            0.1416849           0.195105            0.4326913          
conf.int    Numeric,2           Numeric,2           Numeric,2           Numeric,2           Numeric,2          
estimate    0.2408269           0.06949928          0.5203193           0.4262958           0.2347281          
null.value  0                   0                   0                   0                   0                  
alternative "two.sided"         "two.sided"         "two.sided"         "two.sided"         "two.sided"        
method      "One Sample t-test" "One Sample t-test" "One Sample t-test" "One Sample t-test" "One Sample t-test"
data.name   "rnorm(n, 0.25, 1)" "rnorm(n, 0.25, 1)" "rnorm(n, 0.25, 1)" "rnorm(n, 0.25, 1)" "rnorm(n, 0.25, 1)"
>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a couple of questions. How do I know that the function is effectively doing what I asked it to do? I mean, it is consistent when I do the process "by hand" and the values I expected. However, there is no output except for the final table. Also, the p-value is 0.05; I am doing a two-tailed test, the command recognizes that in each tail I have 0.025 right?  Thank you very very much for your patience and your help.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: This was an amazing answer. Thank you!